JavaScript Event Listener Not Triggering on Search Input - keypress Event
I'm working on a stock market website called MyStok, and I'm trying to implement a search feature that listens for the Enter key press to trigger a search. However, the event listener is not firing, and nothing appears in the console when I press Enter or click the search button. I’m not sure why it isn’t working. Here’s my code:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyStok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg=="
          crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
        <a id="navbar__logo"><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i> MyStok </a>
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
            <li class="navbar__item"><a href="/MyStok/index.html" class="navbar__links">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__item"><a href="/MyStok/about.html" class="navbar__links">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__item"><a href="/MyStok/analyse.html" class="navbar__links" id="analyseButton">Analyse</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__button"><a href="/MyStok/signUp.html" class="button">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main__container">
        <div class="search-bar-container">
            <a id="search-logo"><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i> MyStok </a>
            <div class="search-bar">
                <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for a Stock Ticker...">
                <button id="search-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

JavaScript (app.js):
searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input");

searchInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        console.log("Enter key pressed");
    }
});

What I’ve Tried:
Added an eventListener to trigger on the keypress event for the Enter key.
Tried triggering the event listener with both the button and the Enter key.
Checked the console for errors, but there are no messages or errors showing up.
Expected Behaviour:
When the Enter key is pressed, a message should appear in the console saying "Enter key pressed."
Problem:
The keypress event is not triggering, and I’m not sure why. Is there something wrong with how I set up the event listener?

Buttons (#search-button in the code) don't listen keypresses. Listen keyup (keypress is deprecated on the input element (#search-input).

@Teemu Thank you, I have added that, however the problem, still remains.

No?

Thanks Teemu, that is strange that it is not working on my device then, what do you suggest I do?

Maybe the page is cached?

I am quite new to JS, what would you suggest I do, clear the cache?

Also I really appreciate this, thank you so much

The code seems to be working. Check here: https://codepen.io/Marius-Vantu/pen/GRVdOPV
However, you can test with the JS code embeded directly in the HTML file

Hit CTRL + F5 to force refresh, in DevTools there's also an option to disable cache.

Umm ... Actually, your original code works as well. Make sure the script is really loaded (Check Network tab in DevTools), and no errors occur.

When you're not sure if the code you are running is the latest code, add something innocuous such as console.log("1") at the top level (so it always runs, not dependent on an event) - if the "1" doesn't appear, it's not your code.   Then change this "1" to "2" for the next run etc.
